# How to count elements in group in stimulsoft report

Tags: report, stimulsoft

I have some problem with function Count(). I want to make this report

[Table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQw2B.png)

In first column use function Count() in second some group of element. How I can create this?

Answer (score 1):

You should use **[Processing Duplicates](http://www.stimulsoft.com/en/documentation/online/user-manual/report_internals_output_text_parameters_processing_duplicates.htm)** property of the text component. Set it to **Merge based on Tag**. The **Tag** property should be set to Grouping condition.

Comment: This method work for simple grouping. But if I use nested grouping it does not work. How use function Count() in nested grouping?

Comment: This depends on your report template and data.

Comment: For more details, `Tag` property is a member of `Interaction` property.